# Valloric/YouCompleteMe plugin for Vim

Tags: vim

After installing the Valloric/YouCompleteMe plugin via Vundle I get the following error when I start up vim. I had no issues running the ./install.py script.

```
File "<string>", line 19, in <module>
  File "/Users/simonorlovsky/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/setup.py", line 37, in SetUpSystemPaths
    from ycmd import server_utils as su
  File "/Users/simonorlovsky/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/python/ycm/../../third_party/ycmd/ycmd/server_utils.py", line 25, in <module>
    import io
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
YouCompleteMe unavailable: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I am new to the vim plugin community so I was wondering if anyone has any insight to what the problem may be.

---

*EDIT*

Ultimately the solution was to reinstall macvim and remove the brew version of python on my machine.

Thanks for advice!

Comment: Ok great, I will try that

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for asking this question, I was quite puzzled by this. I had a really tough time getting this plugin to work!

So the steps are as follows

The key thing to get around this specific error is to update vim.

```
brew install macvim --with-override-system-vim
```

After you do this, close your terminal and open a new terminal. Check the version of vim, it should be version 8 now, i.e.

```
vim --version | grep IMproved
```

should have the output:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Apr 20 2017 20:02:24)
```

Note that it will still be the old mac version until you close your terminal and open a new one.

Now remove the incomplete copy of YouCompleteMe:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
```

then open vim and install the plugin again

```
:PluginInstall
```

It should be successful and not have the error reported in this question. However, I found that when I tried to use it, it wasn't working correctly. You're not done yet! You still need to manually install YouCompleteMe. You can do this by (the `--clang-completer` is optional, it's just for if you want semantic support for c-family languages):

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
./install.py --clang-completer
```

You may need to install cmake to do this, so just in case, here is the command:

```
brew install cmake
```

I hope this works for you! Try it out in a python file. Here is the github repo if you want to checkout the readme:
https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe

Let me know if you have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen when you have a faulty YouCompleteMe installation. Removing the plugin and installing it again fixed it for me.